# 4-bit Two's complement overflow

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I have a conceptual (ish) question that I can't understand. I have an assignment and it is telling me to choose which of the following 4-bit binary (2's complement) additions will result in overflow. The following are:

- A. 1011+1001
- B. 1100+1101
- C. 0111+1000
- D. 1010+0110

For A, I got 10100, for B, I got 11001, for C, I got 1111, and for D, I got 10000.

There is only one answer apparently, but A, B, and D all produce an overflow. They end up in 5-bits rather than 4-bits. When I asked the instructor if he meant to say which one of these do NOT produce an overflow but he said that the question is correct. He gave me this hint:

For 4-bit unsigned numbers, overflow means that the sum of 2 numbers can't be represented in unsigned bits. For 4-bit 2's complement, overflow is when the sum of two numbers cannot be represented in 4-bit 2's complement.

This however did not help me, because it is already my understanding - for A, B, D, the sum is unable to be represented in 4-bit 2's complement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must disregard the fifth bit. We are calculating modulo 16, just with 4 bits.

- A -5 + -7 = -12 but result 4
- B -4 + -3 = -7
- C 7 + -8 = -1
- D -6 + 6 = 0

So overflow happens in A.

The fifth bit is absent. *It would in a processor be a something like an overflowish carry flag.*

Overflow can only happen when the signs of both terms are the same: sign1 xor sign2 = 0. And the result has a different sign. *In a processor one normally have a sign flag and such an overflow flag.*

Logical: two negative numbers below -8, or two positive numbers above 7.

Answer (score 1):

For twos-complement representation, the top bit of the representation has a negative value: -(2<sup>k-1</sup>) rather than 2<sup>k-1</sup> for a k bit representation.  This means that when you add them, you can't just look at the carry out of the top full-adder (the 5th bit output in your examples) -- you need to compare it against the carry *in* to the top bit, and you only get an overflow if the two carries are different.  What's actually happening here is that you are *subtracting* the carry in to the top bit, rather than adding it.

So to look at example B in more detail:

```
first value     1 1 0 0
second value    1 1 0 1
carry value    1 1 0 0
result          1 0 0 1
```

So in this case, the carry *in* to the sign bit is the same as the carry out, so there is no overflow -- the 4 bit 2s complement result of 1001 is the correct.